# console.debug not showing in firebase functions log

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

`console.log("Log")`  shows up as an Info level log in the firebase functions log.

`console.debug("Debug")` does not show up at all.

I have the log viewer set to display all log levels.

Is there something I need to do to support different log levels?

This is for the fulfillment for a dialogflow application, if this matters.  I would guess it doesn't but it's my only experience with firebase.

Answer (score 3):

`console.debug` is for internal messages.

You need to use:

- **console.log()** commands have the INFO log level.
- **console.info()** commands have the INFO log level.
- **console.warn()** commands have the ERROR log level.
- **console.error()** commands have the ERROR log level.

Check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs).

Comment: Thanks, what does 'Internal system messages have the DEBUG log level.' even mean?

I guess there is no way to log more detailed stuff at a lower level than INFO?

Comment: It means that is not for you to use. Is for the development team that works on cloud functions